# unexpected error when manipulating list of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling

I have list of data.frame as an output of custom function, so I intend to split each data.frame by its last column, where threshold is given. However, I manipulated the two list nicely, and combined them to get only one table. But I have an error when manipulating this new table. I can't figure out where is issue come from. How can I fix this error ? Can anyone point me out to possibly fix this error ? If this error can be fixed, I want to implement wrapper. How can I easily manipulate list of data.frame ? Any better idea to debug the error ?

mini example :

```
savedDF <- list(
  bar = data.frame(.start=c(12,21,37), .stop=c(14,29,45), .score=c(5,9,4)),
  cat = data.frame(.start=c(18,42,18,42,81), .stop=c(27,46,27,46,114), .score=c(10,5,10,5,34)),
  foo = data.frame(.start=c(3,3,33,3,33,91), .stop=c(24,24,10,24,10,17), .score=c(22,22,6,22,6,7))
)

discardedDF <- list(
  bar = data.frame(.start=c(16,29), .stop=c(20,37), .score=c(2,11)),
  cat = data.frame(.start=c(21,31), .stop=c(23,43), .score=c(1,9)),
  foo = data.frame(.start=c(54, 79), .stop=c(71,93), .score=c(3,8))
)
```

I can manipulate this way :

```
both <- do.call("rbind", c(savedDF, discardedDF))
cn <- c("letter", "seq")
# FIXME : 
DF <- cbind(
  read.table(text = chartr("_", ".", rownames(both)), header=T, sep = ".", col.names = cn), 
  both)
DF <- transform(DF, isPassed = ifelse(.score > 8, "Pass", "Fail"))

by(DF, DF[c("letter", "isPassed")], 
   function(x) write.csv(x[-(1:length(savedDF))], 
                         sprintf("%s_%s_%s.csv", x$letter[1], x$isPassed[1])))
```

But I have an error

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 15 did not have 2 elements
```

Why I have this error ? Can anyone point me out how to fix this ?

my desired output is list of CSV file as follows :

```
bar.saved.Pass.csv
bar.saved.Fail.csv
bar.discarded.Pass.csv
bar.discarded.Fail.csv

cat.saved.Pass.csv
cat.saved.Fail.csv
cat.discarded.Pass.csv
cat.discarded.Fail.csv

foo.saved.Pass.csv
foo.saved.Fail.csv
foo.discarded.Pass.csv
foo.discarded.Fail.csv
```

But I think controlling exported CSV files still not desired. How can I improve functionality of this wrapper ? I intend to let use choose output directory by custom, or more dynamic would be nice. Any idea ? Thanks a lot

Comment: it seems to be an error from `read.table()` complaining that the formatting of line 15 does not match the rest of the document(i.e. it doesn't know how to split line 15 into dataframe columns)

Comment: What is the expected output? How would it look like?

Comment: the problem is with  `rownames(both)` the last 3 names from `discardedDF` are "bar", "cat", "foo" and not "cat.x"... like the rownames from savedDF

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you are trying to do, there might be an easier way to solve your problem, could you elaborate on OmaymaS's question?

Comment: @NathanDay I updated thread where desired output included. Thanks :)

Comment: @NathanDay what if name of input list is varied, so how can I catch real name of list dynamically ? Could you give me possible idea please ?

Comment: @user88911 Where would you want to put the list name once you catch it?

Comment: @NathanDay thanks for your prompt hit. Regarding this line code: isDiscard = ifelse(is.na(seq), "Saved", "Discarded")), could I use variable instead of "Saved", "Discarded" ?

Comment: @user88911 is the `seq` column always `NA` for the discardedDF ? when I wrote this I originally just used a logical vector for `isPassed` and `isDiscard` but changed it for ease of seeing

Comment: @NathanDay I updated my input data, now NA for seq column is gone. Plus, if name of input list is not savedDF, discardedDF, it might be something else, so How can I change the name dynamically in the function ? Is that possible ?

Comment: @NathanDay if no NA in seq column, this code must be updated as well : isDiscard = ifelse(is.na(seq), "Saved", "Discarded")), could I use variable instead of "Saved", "Discarded" ?  Any idea ?

Comment: @user88911 check out the last version of the function and let me know if that's workable

Comment: @user88911 happy to help friend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

both <- do.call("rbind", c(savedDF, discardedDF))
both %<>% rownames_to_column(var = "cn")
both %<>% separate(cn, c("letters", "seq"), sep = "\\.")
both %<>% mutate(isPassed = ifelse(.score > 8, "Passed", "Failed"),
                 isDiscard = ifelse(is.na(seq), "Saved", "Discarded"))

list_of_dfs <- both %>% split(list(.$letters, .$isPassed, .$isDiscard))
csv_names <- paste0("/Users/nathanday/Desktop/", names(list_of_dfs), ".csv") # change this path
mapply(write.csv, list_of_dfs, csv_names)
```

The `%<>%` operator is short hand so `both %<>% rownames_to_columm(var = "cn")` is identical to `both <- rownames_to_column(both, var = "cn")`

To make it more "dynamic" for allowing output path input, you could wrap this in the function structure you already have like this:

```
output_where <- function(output_path, list1, list2) {
    if (!dir.exists(output_path)) {
        dir.create(file.path(output_path))
    }
    both <- do.call(rbind, c(list1, list2))
    both %<>% rownames_to_column(var = "cn")
    both %<>% separate(cn, c("letters", "seq"), sep = "\\.")
    both %<>% mutate(isPassed = ifelse(.score > 8, "Passed", "Failed"), isDiscard = ifelse(is.na(seq), "Saved", "Discarded"))

    list_of_dfs <- both %>% split(list(.$letters, .$isPassed, .$isDiscard))
    csv_names <- paste0(output_path, names(list_of_dfs), ".csv")
    return(mapply(write.csv, list_of_dfs, csv_names))
}

output_where("~/Desktop/", savedDF, discardedDF)
```

for even more dynamics:

```
output_where <- function(output_path, list1, list2) {
    if (!dir.exists(output_path)) {
        dir.create(file.path(output_path))
    }
    names(list1) <- paste("list1", names(list1), sep = ".")
    names(list2) <- paste("list2", names(list2), sep = ".")
    both <- do.call(rbind, c(list1, list2))
    both %<>% rownames_to_column(var = "cn")
    both %<>% separate(cn, c("original_list", "letters", "seq"), sep = "\\.")
    both %<>% mutate(isPassed = ifelse(.score > 8, "Passed", "Failed"))

    list_of_dfs <- both %>% split(list(.$letters, .$isPassed, .$original_list))
    csv_names <- paste0(output_path, names(list_of_dfs), ".csv")
    return(mapply(write.csv, list_of_dfs, csv_names))
}
```

Comment: what warning? "Too few values at 3 locations: 15, 16, 17"?

Comment: Yes, but I think this warning is reasonable. Plus, if I intend to let use choose their output directory by custom, any chance to make this solution more dynamic ?  Thanks :)

Comment: edited for dynamics, let me know if that's what you were thinking